# JQuery Selector not calling function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble with a Jquery selector.

```
  $("#confirmEmailInput").change(function() {
        validate()
        confirmEmail()
    });
```

Above is the selector i'm stuck with. I want the functions to be called when 'confirmEmailInput' has its content changed. It will call the two functions to validate the email address that has been entered into the form. The functions work when called from a button but I can't get the selector to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT 
HTML CODE:

Email Address

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="confirmEmail"> Confirm Email Address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="confirmEmailInput" required />
            </div>
```

Comment: Add your html code to the question as well. Also check `console` for the error and add it to the question.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Are you running in a document.ready event handler? What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Use focus or keypress.

Comment: I don't have any errors in the console. It doesn't seem to be running the functions at all.

Comment: Try `$("#confirmEmailInput").on('input', function() {` also, it's good do describe what _doesn't work_ - Do you get any errors? Does it work, but not how you expect it to? Too many details are missing here

Comment: Unable to replicate, your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/1deas7w3/

Comment: make sure the JS is within a "document.ready" block, or is not rendered until after the HTML. Otherwise the event handler will not attach, because the element won't exist yet. And it's better to put semicolons at the end of each line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try with these

```
$("#confirmEmailInput").keypress(function() {
    validate();
    confirmEmail();
});
```